# Chrome blocking log in form

Tags: google-chrome

I have been developing a system in .NET MVC and have up until had no problems logging in; however today I tried to log in on Chrome and the form is not being submitted instead I get the following error in the console:

> This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context.
>       A warning has been added to the URL bar. 
>       For more information, see [Link Here]

I have verified that the log in page works in another browser (Firefox) and can confirm there is no issue in that browser. Is there something I can do short of converting to a HTTPS site, this is a test server for the company I work at and so they don't use HTTPS on in development websites.

Comment: Well, to me, the error message looks crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect (as Uwe Keim mentions) that you'd want to heed the warning and maybe discuss with your colleagues WHY they aren't testing with HTTPS if they use (or will use) it in Live?  Self signed certificates can be used for these things so it doesn't involve a cost for internal-only development kit.

If that is a no-win situation, perhaps you may gain some benefit by adding it to your trusted sites list?